# ¿Qué rango o qué tengo que agregar en esta validación para que aparte solo reconozca números?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Adjunto código:

```javascript
<TextField onChange={(e) =>{
              setClabe(e.target.value);
              console.log(Clabeinterbancaria.length);
              if(Clabeinterbancaria.length>=18){
                setErrorClabe(true);
                setleyenda("la clabe no debe de contener mas de 18 caracteres");
              }else{
                setErrorClabe(false);
                setleyenda("");
              }
            }} type="usuario" id="Clave" name="clave" placeholder='0000 0000 0000 0000' error={errorClabe}  helperText={Leyenda} variant="filled" className='text' inputProps={{style:{padding:0}}}></TextField>
            <FormHelperText>CLABE INTERBANCARIA</FormHelperText>
```

O sea, el mensaje que sí se pasa de los dígitos manda el mensaje, pero ahora quiero agregarle para que solo reconozca números.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera.

```
const allowedDigits = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
const number = "a8899096523423"
const numberElements = number.split("");
const isNotValid = numberElements.some(x => !allowedDigits.includes(x))
```

Eso sería para validar toda la cadena. Otra manera es

```
if (isNaN(Number(e.target.value))) {
   // haces lo que sea si no es un numero lo introducido
}else{
   // haces lo que sea si es un numero
}
```

De esta última validas la entrada antes de guardar el dato o lo que sea